# How to convert this LINQ to its equivalent Expression Tree and make it performant

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Update: You can skip the second part of this question as George already helped answer the first part.

**Part I:** I am trying to convert the LINQ below

```
childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));
```

to its equivalent Expression but I can't get Step 6 to produce a result. I also don't think I am using Expression.Constant in Steps 2 - 6 as appropriate but it seems to be working, for now at least.

Any help in fixing this would be much appreciated!

---

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public void SO_Question()
    {
        Parent parentItem       = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent" };
        parentItem.Children     = new List<Child>();
        List<Child> childItems  = new List<Child>() {   new Child() { ParentID = parentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 1" }, 
                                                        new Child() { ParentID = parentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 2" },
                                                        new Child() { ParentID = Guid.NewGuid(),ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 3" } 
                                                    };


        // Linq query that I am trying to write using Expressions
        childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from LINQ: " + parentItem.Children.Count);   
        parentItem.Children.Clear();

        Type parentEntityType   = parentItem.GetType();
        Type childEntityCollType= childItems.GetType();
        Type childEntityType    = childEntityCollType.GetGenericArguments()[0];


        //1. (x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
        ParameterExpression predParam   = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "x");
        Expression left                 = Expression.Property(predParam, childEntityType.GetProperty("ParentID"));
        Expression right                = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentItem), "ID");
        Expression equality             = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        LambdaExpression le             = Expression.Lambda(equality, new ParameterExpression[] { predParam });


        //2. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
        Expression targetConstant       = Expression.Constant(childItems, childEntityCollType);
        Expression whereBody            = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new Type[] { childEntityType }, targetConstant, le);
        Func<IEnumerable> whereLambda   = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(whereBody).Compile();
        object whereResult              = whereLambda.Invoke();


        //3. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList()
        Expression toListConstant   = Expression.Constant(whereResult, whereResult.GetType());
        Expression toListBody       = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "ToList", new Type[] { childEntityType }, toListConstant);
        Func<IEnumerable> listLambda= Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(toListBody).Compile();
        object toListResult         = listLambda.Invoke();


        //5. (y => parentItem.Children.Add(y))
        ParameterExpression feParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "y");
        Expression addConst         = Expression.Constant(parentItem, parentEntityType);
        Expression childAccessor    = Expression.Property(addConst, parentEntityType.GetProperty("Children"));
        Expression body             = Expression.Call(childAccessor, "Add", null, feParam);
        LambdaExpression exp2       = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression[] { feParam });


        //6. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));
        Expression targetConst2 = Expression.Constant(toListResult, toListResult.GetType());
        Expression whereBody2   = Expression.Call(targetConst2, toListResult.GetType().GetMethod("ForEach"), exp2);
        Delegate whereLambda2   = Expression.Lambda(whereBody2, feParam).Compile();
        whereLambda.Invoke();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from Expressions: " + parentItem.Children.Count);    
    }
```

**Part II:** After @George fixed my issue I have hit a performance problem. I need to run the two lambdas thousands of times within a loop and currently it is very slow, probably because the expression tree is generated every time. How can I get around this? 
I've restructured the code and simplified it a bit from my initial question.

In the code below parentItem is captured in the closure. How can i rewrite this so that I can use the expression from 1, 2 and 3 and only supply parentItem (on 2 and 3) as a variable to the lambda on every run?

---

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public SingleChild SingleChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SingleChild
{
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void SO_Question2()
{
    Parent newParentItem1 = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent1" };
    Parent newParentItem2 = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent2" };
    Parent newParentItem3 = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent3" };

    newParentItem1.Children = new List<Child>();
    newParentItem2.Children = new List<Child>();
    newParentItem3.Children = new List<Child>();

    List<Child> childItems = new List<Child>() {   
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem1.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 1" }, 
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem1.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 2" },
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem2.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 3" },
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem2.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 4" },
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem2.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 5" },
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem2.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 6" },
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem2.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 7" } 
    };
    List<Parent> parentCollection = new List<Parent>() { newParentItem1, newParentItem2, newParentItem3 }; // In reality this can be a collection of over 2000 items


    // Linq query that I am trying to write using Expressions
    foreach (Parent parentItem in parentCollection)
    {
        parentItem.Children.Clear();
        childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from LINQ: " + newParentItem1.Children.Count);
    newParentItem1.Children.Clear();
    newParentItem2.Children.Clear();
    newParentItem3.Children.Clear();


    Type parentEntityType = parentCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type childEntityCollType = childItems.GetType();
    Type childEntityType = childEntityCollType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    Parent parentVariable = parentCollection.First();

    // 1. parentItem.Children.Clear()
    var childCollection = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentVariable), "Children");
    Expression clearBody = Expression.Call(childCollection, typeof(ICollection<Child>).GetMethod("Clear"));
    Expression<System.Action> bodyLambda = Expression.Lambda<System.Action>(clearBody);
    System.Action compiledClear = bodyLambda.Compile();

    // How can I change 1 and 2 so that they are not recreated with every iteration?
    // My problem is that parentItem changes but is captured in the closure

    //2. (x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
    ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "x");
    Expression left = Expression.Property(predParam, childEntityType.GetProperty("ParentID"));
    Expression right = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentVariable), "ID");
    Expression equality = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    Expression<Func<Child, bool>> le = Expression.Lambda<Func<Child, bool>>(equality, new ParameterExpression[] { predParam });
    Func<Child, bool> compileLambda = le.Compile();


    //3. (y => parentItem.Children.Add(y))
    ParameterExpression feParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "y");
    Expression addConst = Expression.Constant(parentVariable, parentEntityType);
    Expression childAccessor = Expression.Property(addConst, parentEntityType.GetProperty("Children"));
    Expression body = Expression.Call(childAccessor, "Add", null, feParam);
    Expression<Action<Child>> exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Action<Child>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { feParam });
    Action<Child> compileExp2 = exp2.Compile();

    foreach (Parent parentItem in parentCollection)
    {
        parentVariable = parentItem;

        compiledClear();
        childItems.Where(compileLambda).ToList().ForEach(compileExp2);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from Expressions: " + parentCollection.First().Children.Count);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for giving others the opportunity to downvote me ;) Secondly, what do you want to de exactly?. If you want to call endless times you MUST compile and reuse that delegate. If you have closures try to pass them as parameters instead of calling Expression.Constant. Use Expression.Constant ONLY if the value it's a value type or string. Otherwise try to inject them into your expressions as parameters.

Comment: @Goeorge Lica Sorry! But I did mention that you answered the first part of my question and I added Part II because I didnt want to start a new post. In Part II, I am asking how I can improve the performance if this is being called in a loop. You and Shlomo seem to be at odds regards compiling the delegate. He suggests creating the closure outside and reassigning the value at run time in the loop whereas you say that I should pass them as parameters (how? as Where takes func<T,bool>) or inject (again how?).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void SO_Question()
    {
        Parent parentItem = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent" };
        parentItem.Children = new List<Child>();
        List<Child> childItems = new List<Child>() {   
            new Child() { ParentID = parentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 1" }, 
            new Child() { ParentID = parentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 2" },
            new Child() { ParentID = Guid.NewGuid(),ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 3" } 
        };


        // Linq query that I am trying to write using Expressions
        childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from LINQ: " + parentItem.Children.Count);
        parentItem.Children.Clear();

        Type parentEntityType = parentItem.GetType();
        Type childEntityCollType = childItems.GetType();
        Type childEntityType = childEntityCollType.GetGenericArguments()[0];


        //1. (x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
        ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "x");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(predParam, childEntityType.GetProperty("ParentID"));
        Expression right = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentItem), "ID");
        Expression equality = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        LambdaExpression le = Expression.Lambda(equality, new ParameterExpression[] { predParam });


        //2. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
        Expression targetConstant = Expression.Constant(childItems, childEntityCollType);
        Expression whereBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new Type[] { childEntityType }, targetConstant, le);
        Func<IEnumerable> whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(whereBody).Compile();
        object whereResult = whereLambda.Invoke();


        //3. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList()
        Expression toListConstant = Expression.Constant(whereResult, whereResult.GetType());
        Expression toListBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "ToList", new Type[] { childEntityType }, toListConstant);
        Func<IEnumerable> listLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(toListBody).Compile();
        object toListResult = listLambda.Invoke();


        //5. (y => parentItem.Children.Add(y))
        ParameterExpression feParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "y");
        Expression addConst = Expression.Constant(parentItem, parentEntityType);
        Expression childAccessor = Expression.Property(addConst, parentEntityType.GetProperty("Children"));
        Expression body = Expression.Call(childAccessor, "Add", null, feParam);
        LambdaExpression exp2 = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression[] { feParam });


        //6. childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));
        Expression targetConst2 = Expression.Constant(toListResult, toListResult.GetType());
        Expression whereBody2 = Expression.Call(targetConst2, toListResult.GetType().GetMethod("ForEach"), exp2);

        Delegate d = Expression.Lambda(whereBody2).Compile();
        d.DynamicInvoke();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from Expressions: " + parentItem.Children.Count);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the DynamicInvoke() before but it didn't work, after looking at your solution I went back and tried to see why mine didn't work and realized I was calling it on the wrong lambda! Instead of whereResult1.DymanicInvoke() (what you have as Delegate d I had as Delegate whereResult2) I, by accident, called whereResult.DynamicInvoke. Lost a whole day on it!! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KShan With pleasure!

Comment: I thought Expression.Constant was only used to evaluate constants. Why is it being used in this case with a List and why does it work?

Comment: think of Expression.Constant as a tool for introducing closures in your code. If it is a "value" type or a string or something that can ne introduced directly as  a "value" in your expression then that value will be burned directly otherwise a "closure" will be build. How ? When you will compile your code, an anonymous type will be created and it will have all properties that your compiled method use as "constants" + your new method.

Comment: I've updated a the question after running into a performance issue. Do you think you can help with the fix?

Answer (score 0):

**For Question 2 only:**
You could make the parent a variable to the lambda. However, that wouldn't mirror your LINQ code.

The alternative is to make a dummy variable, build your expression against the dummy variable, then your loop will set the dummy variable. I commented out the first lambda because it wasn't compiling and doesn't seem relevant to this question:

```
public static void SO_Question2()
{
    Parent newParentItem = new Parent() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Parent" };
    newParentItem.Children = new List<Child>();
    List<Child> childItems = new List<Child>() {   
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 1" }, 
        new Child() { ParentID = newParentItem.ID, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 2" },
        new Child() { ParentID = Guid.NewGuid(),ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Child 3" } 
    };
    List<Parent> parentCollection = new List<Parent>() { newParentItem }; // In reality this can be a collection of over 2000 items

    // Linq query that I am trying to write using Expressions
    foreach (Parent parentItem in parentCollection)
    {
        childItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID).ToList().ForEach(y => parentItem.Children.Add(y));
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from LINQ: " + newParentItem.Children.Count);
    newParentItem.Children.Clear();


    Type parentEntityType = parentCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type childEntityCollType = childItems.GetType();
    Type childEntityType = childEntityCollType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    Parent parentVariable = parentCollection.First();
    // 1. parentItem.Children.Clear()
    //var childCollection = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentVariable), "Children");
    //Expression clearBody = Expression.Call(childCollection, typeof(List<Child>).GetMethod("Clear"));
    //Delegate bodyLambda = Expression.Lambda(clearBody).Compile();
    //bodyLambda.DynamicInvoke();


    // How can I change 2 and 3 so that they are not recreated with every iteration?
    // My problem is that parentItem changes but is captured in the closure

    //2. (x => x.ParentID == parentItem.ID)
    ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "x");
    Expression left = Expression.Property(predParam, childEntityType.GetProperty("ParentID"));
    Expression right = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(parentVariable), "ID");
    Expression equality = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    Expression<Func<Child, bool>> le = Expression.Lambda<Func<Child, bool>>(equality, new ParameterExpression[] { predParam });
    Func<Child, bool> compileLambda = le.Compile();


    //3. (y => parentItem.Children.Add(y))
    ParameterExpression feParam = Expression.Parameter(childEntityType, "y");
    Expression addConst = Expression.Constant(parentVariable, parentEntityType);
    Expression childAccessor = Expression.Property(addConst, parentEntityType.GetProperty("Children"));
    Expression body = Expression.Call(childAccessor, "Add", null, feParam);
    Expression<Action<Child>> exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Action<Child>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { feParam });
    Action<Child> compileExp2 = exp2.Compile();

    foreach (Parent parentItem in parentCollection)
    {
        parentVariable = parentItem;
        childItems.Where(compileLambda).ToList().ForEach(compileExp2);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count from Expressions: " + parentCollection.First().Children.Count);
}
```

Notice that the compile (the expensive part) runs only once. The execution runs multiple times. This works because `Expression.Constant(parentVariable)` checks every time for whatever is in that reference location. Change the reference, you change the variable. Also note that `parentVariable` can be static, public, whatever. It doesn't have to be a local.

Comment: This solution does not work as the closure is created on the initial value and changing the reference of parentVariable does not alter it. I've updated the question with a few more parents so that you can easily run and view the results. I've also fixed the part where the .Clear() was not working.